# Extracting data values from a plot

Tags: plotting

I found that the fact is very useful that a plot sometimes contains all the original data needed to reconstruct that plot. This is very helpful for me because sometimes I need to retrieve and analysis the numerical data in plots I produced in the past. It's much easier for me(in the sense of organization of projects) to just save the plots in notebooks rather than save the numerical data in some separated files.

For example:

```
data1 = {{1., 2.}, {2., 3.}, {3., 1.}};
pic1 = ListPlot[data1, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

I can get the data back using

```
Cases[pic1, Line[x__] -> x, ∞]
(* {{{1., 2.}, {2., 3.}, {3., 1.}}} *)
```

This works great most of the time, but sometimes when I specified a plot range, some data are lost:

```
data2 = Table[{x, Cos[x]^2}, {x, -π/2, π/2, π/8}] // N;
ListPlot[data2, Joined -> True]
pic2 = ListPlot[data2, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {0, 0.5}}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]
[image]

```
Graphics[Cases[pic2, _Line, ∞], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Note that the data are lost only at the vertical direction. So are there ways to tell Mathematica to save all the data into the plot?

Comment: You can `PlotRange -> All` in `ListPlot` and clip the graphics afterthen by `Show[#, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {0, 0.5}}] &`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Show` to impose `PlotRange`:

```
data2 = Table[{x, Cos[x]^2}, {x, -π/2, π/2, π/8}];
ListPlot[data2, Joined -> True]
pic2 = Show[ListPlot[data2, Joined -> True], PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {0, 0.5}}]
```

Then this will give you everything:

```
Graphics[Cases[pic2, _Line, ∞], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> True]
```

Answer (score 4):

Although this is not really an answer to your question, I would like to point out another simple way to make data persistent without the need for external files. This may be beneficial in the long run, because the structure of `Graphics`, `Plot`s etc. may change over time (and has done so a few times already), leading to potential legacy problems.

`Button` together with `With` can store data very nicely across sessions and does not take up a lot of notebook real estate. Consider this:

```
data = Table[FresnelC[x], {x, 0, 3, 0.05}];
With[{data = data}, Button["data", Print[data]]]
```

Now you can reproduce `data` at leisure by pressing the relevant button even across sessions.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, once you re-evaluate the generating cell, the content will be overwritten, so you´d have to take care doing that only when desired.

Depending on your requirement, this can be built upon:

```
With[{data = data}, Button["data", CellPrint[TextCell[Defer[savedat = data;], "Input"]]]]
```

Now pressing the button will output a deferred expression you can evaluate and use with ease.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plus, you can style your button any old how (here, much redundant):

```
With[{data = data}, Button[ListLinePlot[data], 
  CellPrint[TextCell[Defer[savedat = data;], "Input"]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For large data sets, you might also want to consider using `Compress` at some stage. To decouple buttons from their generating cell, you could e.g. cut&paste them or do similar things programmatically, too.

Comment: That's really helpful!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you do not consider it OT :D I ran into some issues doing similar things when there was a change in the color handling (RGBColorvs. Hue, I think) during some prior version switch. For large sets, you should also consider using Compress additionally.