# How to not include data value outside plot range in the plot

Tags: plotting

Consider this list plot

```
ls = Table[Sin[t], {t, 0, 100, 0.1}];
p = ListPlot[ls, PlotRange -> {{0., 0.1}, All}, DataRange -> {0, 1}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

If we look at the data in the plot, we see that all the data in `ls` are included in the plot.

```
ls2 = p[[1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]];
Dimensions[ls2]
(* {1001, 2} *)

ListPlot[ls2, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Sometimes this is really helpful because we can just retrieve the data at a later time from the plots and don't need to regenerate the data again. But sometimes I'm only interested in the range set in the `ListPlot`, and saving all the data is kindly of wasting of space, especially when I have many plots in a notebook, the notebook size becomes very large and not very responsive.

So are there simple ways to tell `ListPlot` to not include the data outside the plot range, other than manually select the data before plot?

P.S. Sometimes, `ListPlot` does drop the data outside the range, see example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38576/extracting-data-values-from-a-plot).

Comment: You could assign `p[[1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]]` to whatever you want ...

Comment: @belisarius What do you mean? I think maybe I didn't say clearly, I meant to make p[[1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]] only contains the data points that in the plot range I set.

Comment: Whether save the graphics as raster image fulfill your need? Anyway you can always choose to plot only part of your data (`ls`).

Comment: No, there's no documented (or undocumented, AFAIK) feature in plot to do this. If you don't need a full tank, don't fill it (truncate the data list at the source). Fiddling with it *ex post facto* means possibly breaking things later in the chain (e.g., carrying the "baggage" allows one to use say things like `Show` with differing options from the original plot).

Comment: @rasher but why sometime `ListPlot` do drop the "baggage" if we set the vertical plot range, as linked in the question?

Comment: @Silvia I did consider raster, but it requires the frontend, which is quite slow for generate many plots.

Comment: So why not just plot the data you want?

Comment: @Silvia I guess I'm too lazy :) But seriously, usually the data I generate is a one dimensional list contains only the y value and without the x values, so it would be inconvenient to regenerate all the x values and select out part of the data, especially I usually adjust the plotrange very often. For example, I have a list consists of 100 data points run from -1.2 to 3.1, then if I want to plot the range 2.1 to 2.9, I have to do something like `dt = (3.1 - (-1.2))/(100 - 1); ListPlot[Select[Transpose[{Range[-1.2, 3.1, dt], ls}], 
  2.1 <= #[[1]] <= 2.9 &]]`.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Maybe consider constructing an `InterpolationFunction` then `Plot` it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @rasher's comment is correct and you can plot the points you need by truncating the list. You can make a function that does that. I named mine (ironically) `economicListPlot` but it took a lot of copy-pasting to account for different values of the options so it could do with a tidy up

```
economicListPlot[data_ /; VectorQ[data], opts : OptionsPattern[ListPlot]] :=

 Module[{newopts, plotRange1, dataRange1, ind1, ind2},
  With[{
    plotRange = PlotRange /. FilterRules[{opts}, PlotRange], 
    dataRange = DataRange /. FilterRules[{opts}, DataRange]
    },
   If[dataRange === DataRange,



    If[plotRange === PlotRange || plotRange === All || plotRange === Automatic,

     ListPlot[data, Evaluate[opts]],(*no plotrange or datarange defined*)

     newopts = Sequence @@ Cases[{opts}, Except[HoldPattern[PlotRange -> _]]];
     plotRange1 = If[VectorQ@plotRange, plotRange, First@plotRange];
     ind1 = IntegerPart@Max[First@plotRange1, 1];
     ind2 = IntegerPart@Max[Last@plotRange1, 1];
     ListPlot[data[[ind1 ;; ind2]], 
      Evaluate@newopts, 
      PlotRange -> {Automatic, 
        Evaluate@
         Complement[ 
          plotRange, {plotRange1}]}(*plotrange defined only*)]
     ],


    If[plotRange === All || plotRange === Automatic,
     ListPlot[data, Evaluate[opts]],
     newopts = Sequence @@ Cases[{opts}, Except[HoldPattern[PlotRange -> _]]];
     newopts = Sequence @@ Cases[{newopts}, Except[HoldPattern[DataRange -> _]]];
     plotRange1 = If[VectorQ@plotRange, plotRange, First@plotRange];
     dataRange1 = If[VectorQ@dataRange, dataRange, First@dataRange];
     ind1 = Max[Ceiling[(plotRange1[[1]] - dataRange1[[1]])/
         Subtract @@ Reverse@dataRange1 (Length[data])], 1];
     ind2 = Min[Ceiling[
        ind1 + (Subtract @@ Reverse@plotRange1* (Length[data]))/
         Subtract @@ Reverse@dataRange1 ], Length[data]
       ];
     ListPlot[data[[ind1 ;; ind2]], Evaluate@newopts, 
      PlotRange -> {All, 
        Evaluate@Complement[ plotRange, {plotRange1}]}, 
      DataRange -> 
       Evaluate@
        plotRange1](*both plotrange and datarange defined*)
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

Anyhow, it does what you want:

```
    data = Table[Sin[t], {t, 0, 100, 0.1}];
p = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0., 0.1}, All}, DataRange -> {0, 1},
    Joined -> True];
p2 = economicListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0., 0.1}, All}, 
   DataRange -> {0, 1}, Joined -> True];

p2[[1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]] // Dimensions
(*{102 , 2}*)

p[[1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]] // Dimensions
(*{1001 , 2}*)
```

and the plots are the "same":

```
GraphicsRow[{p, p2}]
```

[image]

but if you go to wider plot/data ranges there is some difference (my index gymnastics are a little off) so I'd be cautious on how I'd use this:

```
Show[ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{1.1, 1.3}, All}, 
  DataRange -> {0, 20}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.01]], 
 economicListPlot[data, Joined -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{1.1, 1.3}, All}, DataRange -> {0, 20}, 
  PlotStyle -> Orange]]
```

[image: discrepancy]