# Extract data from DateListPlot, limited by PlotRange

Tags: plotting, expression-manipulation, date-and-time

Extracting the *points from a line* in a ListPlot in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31870/7252) uses

```
points = Cases[Normal@plot, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity];
```

This works in DateListPlot (provided `Joined->True`) (example below, using `Last` to get the y-axis data only)

```
Clear[test,plot,points];
test={{"2010",1},{"2011",2},{"2012",3},{"2014",4},{"2015",5},{"2016",6}};
plot=DateListPlot[test,Joined->True]
points=Last/@Flatten[Cases[Normal@plot,Line[pts_]:>pts,Infinity],1]
```

[image]

```
(*OUTPUT
{1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.}
```

However, when the plot is limited by `PlotRange` using date values (lower plot), the function returns the entire list of points.

```
plot2=DateListPlot[test,Joined->True,PlotRange->{{"2012","2015"},{0,6}}]
points2=Last/@Flatten[Cases[Normal@plot2,Line[pts_]:>pts,Infinity],1]
```

[image]

```
(*OUTPUT
{1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.}
```

Is there a function, like `points` which can return *only the points displayed on the plot* in DateListPlot  under 'PlotRange` ?

Comment: You can just use `Select` on the result with conditions similar to those in `PlotRange`.

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45537/how-to-not-include-data-value-outside-plot-range-in-the-plot)

Comment: @Kuba Appreciated.  Pickett is along those lines too and delves into the plot function to retrieve the bounds

Comment: @rasher Thanks. The linked answer is a serious Module indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
points2 = 
 With[{range = Part[PlotRange /. Options[plot2], 1]}, 
  Select[Flatten[Cases[Normal@plot2, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity], 1],
     First@range <= First@# && First@# <= Last@range &][[All, 2]]]
```

With `plot2` as in your example:

> {3., 4., 5.}

Comment: Yes!  I was hoping someone could retrieve the values with `Options` magic.

Comment: I worked through what you did.  Using the `Options` to make a set of replace rules and `PlotRange` as the "target of those replace rules" is very neat.  I learned something new (again).

Comment: @PlaysDice I'm glad you liked it! :)

Answer (score 2):

A variant of Pickett's answer:

- using new-in-10 [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html)
- with a terse way to extract the plot range
- extended to either Line or Point data
- written as a reusable function

Code:

```
inrangeData[gr_Graphics] := 
  Select[Rectangle @@ (PlotRange[gr]\[Transpose]) // RegionMember] /@ 
    Cases[Normal @ gr, _Point | _Line, -1][[All, 1]]
```

Test:

```
inrangeData[plot2]
```

> ```
> {{{3.53436*10^9, 3.}, {3.59752*10^9, 4.}, {3.62906*10^9, 5.}}}
> ```

```
ListPlot[Prime @ Range @ 25, PlotRange -> {20, 40}]

% // inrangeData
```

[image]

> ```
> {{{9., 23.}, {10., 29.}, {11., 31.}, {12., 37.}}}
> ```

The extra bracket depth is there to allow the function to handle plots with multiple lines or sets:

```
ListLinePlot[
  Table[{k, PDF[BinomialDistribution[50, p], k]}, {p, {0.3, 0.5, 0.8}}, {k, 0, 50}], 
  PlotRange -> {0.08, 0.15},
  Filling -> Axis
]

% // inrangeData
```

[image]

> ```
> {
>  {
>   {11.838, 0.08}, {11.8528, 0.08035}, {12., 0.0838297}, {13., 0.105017},
>   {14., 0.118948}, {15., 0.122347}, {16., 0.1147}, {17., 0.0983144},
>   {17.8527, 0.08035}, {17.8693, 0.08}
>  },
>  {
>   {22.0685, 0.08}, {22.089, 0.08035}, {23., 0.0959617}, {24., 0.107957},
>   {25., 0.112275}, {26., 0.107957}, {27., 0.0959617}, {27.911, 0.08035},
>   {27.9315, 0.08}
>  },
>  {
>   {37.1629, 0.08}, {37.1755, 0.08035}, {38., 0.103275}, {39., 0.127108},
>   {40., 0.139819}, {41., 0.136409}, {42., 0.116922}, {43., 0.0870116},
>   {43.2105, 0.08035}, {43.2216, 0.08}
>  }
> }
> ```