# FFT of data to obtain resonance frequencies and correct amplitudes

Tags: data, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have often to do with experimental data (with a certain length and given sampling frequency) where I obtain trajetories of moving objects in 2d. Then I am interested to find out what the corresponding freqency spectrum is, if the objects are excited by external sources and what the resonance frequencies and amplitudes are.

To do that I could use the example which I translated from [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html).

Example:

I produce data containing a 50 Hz sinusoid of amplitude 0.7 and a 120 Hz sinusoid of amplitude 1.

```
fs = 1000;(*Sampling frequency*)
tp = 1/fs;(*Sampling period*)
l = 1500;(*Length of signal*)

t = Range[0, l - 1, 1]*tp;(*Time vector*)

x = 0.7*Sin[2*Pi*50*t] + Sin[2*Pi*120*t];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{t[[1 ;; 50]], x[[1 ;; 50]]}], 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", "x (t)"}]
```

[image]

Now I want to calculate the frequency spectrum, which should show two peaks at 50 Hz with amplitude 0.7 and at 120 Hz with amplitude 1.

```
f = fs*Range[0, l/2, 1]/l;

y = Fourier[x, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];

p2 = Abs[y/l];

p1 = p2[[1 ;; l/2 + 1]];

p1[[2 ;; Length@p1 - 1]] = 2*p1[[2 ;; Length@p1 - 1]];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{f, p1}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"f (Hz)", "Abs[p1(f)]"}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

So far, I can reproduce what is shown by [Matlab](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) with their example code.

[image]

**Question: 
What would be a Matematica-like solution for my problem?**

I have seen that Mathematica provides the function `Periodogram`. With that I tried the following:

```
plot = Periodogram[x, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}, SampleRate -> fs, 
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"f (Hz)", "Abs[p1(f)]"}, 
   PlotRange -> Full, ScalingFunctions -> "Absolute"]
```

[image]

As one can see: the frequencies are found, but the amplitudes are not correct.

Once I would find the correct amplitudes with `Periodogram` I could use a [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50450/extract-data-from-datelistplot-limited-by-plotrange) from Mr.Wizard to retrieve the data lists of the frequency and amplitude.

```
data = Select[Rectangle @@ (PlotRange[plot]\[Transpose]) // RegionMember] /@ 
  Cases[Normal@plot, _Point | _Line, -1][[All, 1]];

ListLinePlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"f (Hz)", "Abs[p1(f)]"},
  PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: The amplitudes shown in `Periodogram` depend on the window function. If you know which one matlab uses you could use the same in Mathematica. But for your original problem i think the manual route via `Fourier` is a good way to go.

Comment: If you are after amplitudes I would stick to `Fourier` and choose appropriate `FourierParameters`. The answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558) may be of some help. If I have time I will post a full answer.

Comment: @Hugh: Thanks a lot for the link.

Comment: Prony's method will recover frequencies and amplitudes. Check [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94713/51) for implementation code. When I change a few variable names from that code to match the definitions above I get the desired values.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: Thank you very much for your mentioned link and also to the link to the discussion on Wolfram Community: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/528474?p_p_auth=33hR9Jgo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Abs` for the Fourier transform of the data (`Fourier`), and do not forget to normalise:

```
absft = Abs@Fourier[x] // Chop; 
ListPlot[absft[[1 ;; Length[absft]/3]]/Max[absft], PlotRange -> All, 
Filling -> Bottom, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.015]]
```

[image]

Comment: @mrz the indices in `p1`should be integers...